# Background image zoomed too much on mobile

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive-design

I have strange problem with my RWD page. I have a background image with following styles:

```
#background-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url('../landing.jpeg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 85% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

When I'm in mobile mode in Chrome DevTools (and FF too), everything looks ok:

[image]

But on real mobile browser this background becomes too large:

[image]

What can be the reason? My mobile browser is Chrome 63 on Android and my desktop browser is Chrome 59 on Ubuntu.

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" content="initial-scale-1">`

Comment: So, should I remove it? I just added it to solve problems with Google Maps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the `background-attachment: fixed` setting is not working on mobile browsers...

Try removing `background-attachment` property and change the `position` prop to `fixed`, like below:

```
#background-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url('../landing.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 85% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Hope this will help...

Answer (score -2):

Try to add inside HEAD:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: I already had this tag without `maximum-scale` and `user-scalable` settings, although I added it as you suggested - and doesn't work.